# Trying to get values of favorited Item from a morphMany Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

My Application allows users to like both post and comments with a morphMany relationship

Favorite Model:

```
public function favorited()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}

public function user(){

    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}
```

My Trait

```
trait Favoriteable
{ 
  public function favorites()
 {
    return $this->morphMany(Favorite::class, 'favorited');
 }
}
```

My Post

```
public function favorites()
{
    return $this->morphMany(Favorite::class, 'favorited');
}
```

My Comment

```
public function favorites()
{
    return $this->morphMany(Favorite::class, 'favorited');
}
```

My Users

```
 public function favorites(){
    return $this->hasMany(Favorite::class);
}
```

Now in blade I am trying to get the user favorited activities.. I have tried $activity->subject->favorited and more nothing works but when I dd($activity->subject->favorited) I get this:

```
Post {#682 ▼
#guarded: []
#fillable: array:4 [▶]
#appends: array:2 [▶]
#connection: "mysql"
#table: null
#primaryKey: "id"
#keyType: "int"
+incrementing: true
#with: []
#withCount: []
#perPage: 15
+exists: true
+wasRecentlyCreated: false
#attributes: array:7 [▼
"id" => 14
"user_id" => 1
"author_id" => 3
"content" => "Awesome Albert.."
"total_comments" => 0
"created_at" => "2018-05-16 13:02:18"
"updated_at" => "2018-05-16 13:02:18"
]
#original: array:7 [▼
"id" => 14
"user_id" => 1
"author_id" => 3
"content" => "Awesome Albert.."
"total_comments" => 0
"created_at" => "2018-05-16 13:02:18"
"updated_at" => "2018-05-16 13:02:18"
]
#casts: []
#dates: []
#dateFormat: null
#events: []
#observables: []
#relations: []
#touches: []
+timestamps: true
#hidden: []
#visible: []
```

}

when I dd($activity->result):

```
Favorite {#685 ▼
#guarded: []
#with: array:1 [▼
0 => "favorited"
]
#connection: "mysql"
#table: null
#primaryKey: "id"
#keyType: "int"
+incrementing: true
#withCount: []
#perPage: 15
+exists: true
+wasRecentlyCreated: false
#attributes: array:6 [▼
"id" => 30
"user_id" => 3
"favorited_id" => 14
"favorited_type" => "App\Post"
"created_at" => "2018-05-18 16:01:56"
"updated_at" => "2018-05-18 16:01:56"
]
#original: array:6 [▼
"id" => 30
"user_id" => 3
"favorited_id" => 14
"favorited_type" => "App\Post"
"created_at" => "2018-05-18 16:01:56"
"updated_at" => "2018-05-18 16:01:56"
]
#casts: []
#dates: []
#dateFormat: null
#appends: []
#events: []
#observables: []
#relations: array:1 [▼
"favorited" => Post {#720 ▼
  #guarded: []
  #fillable: array:4 [▶]
  #appends: array:2 [▶]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:7 [▼
    "id" => 14
    "user_id" => 1
    "author_id" => 3
    "content" => "Awesome Albert.."
    "total_comments" => 0
    "created_at" => "2018-05-16 13:02:18"
    "updated_at" => "2018-05-16 13:02:18"
  ]
  #original: array:7 [▼
    "id" => 14
    "user_id" => 1
    "author_id" => 3
    "content" => "Awesome Albert.."
    "total_comments" => 0
    "created_at" => "2018-05-16 13:02:18"
    "updated_at" => "2018-05-16 13:02:18"
  ]
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #events: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
 }
]
#touches: []
+timestamps: true
#hidden: []
#visible: []
#fillable: []
```

}

Comment: What are `activity` and `subject`?

Comment: Activity is the model store users actions whenever there is a Favorite activity. Subject is the model on which the favorite action was taken. E.g for comments, I get the comment_id and the type will be App\Comment

Comment: Please add the result of `dd($activity->subject);` to your question.

Comment: Here is the result of dd($activity->subject)

Comment: Shouldn't you use something like `$user->favorites`?

Comment: $activity has all favorites by the user through a hasMany relationship

Comment: It doesn't feel like we made any real progress. What model(s) do you have and what models do you want to get? Maybe post the controller code that belongs to that view. What model is `$activity`?